Non-asymptotic upper-bound on the partial sum of binomial coefficients
It is well-known that the partial sum $\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}$ has no closed form. Assuming that $k \leq n/2$, then the largest summand is the last one, so that we obtain the trivial bound $\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i} \leq k \binom{n}{k}$.
However, this bound is not tight.
Assuming that $k \leq n/2$, it is possible to obtain something a bit better using the bounds given by the binary entropy function:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i} &\leq 2^{n H(k/n)}, \\ 
\binom{n}{d} \geq& \sqrt{\frac{n}{8 k(n-k)}} 2^{n H(k/n)}
\end{align}
$$
By combining the two one obtains:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i} \leq \sqrt{\frac{8 k(n-k)}{n}} \binom{n}{k}
$$
My question is: are there better bounds of the kind $\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i} \leq F(n,k) \binom{n}{k}$, where $F(n, k)$ is a "simple" function like in the above examples?
EDIT: ideally, I'd prefer something that always works, but it is OK to assume that $k \leq \alpha n$ with $\alpha < 1/2$.

It probably depends a bit on what range of $k$ you are interested in, and what kind of application. If $k$ is small a better bound is $\binom{n}{k} + (k-1) \binom{n}{k-1} = (1 + k(k-1) / (n-k+1)) \binom{n}{k}$. If $k$ is close to $n/2$ you can't get anything better than $\sqrt{2 \pi n}$ or so, because $\binom{n}{n/2} \sim \sqrt{2/\pi} n^{-1/2} 2^n$.

Thanks for pointing out what happens when $k \approx n/2$. I edited the question to make it more precise.

One thing you can do is compare $\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}$ with a geometric series. Assume $k \le n/2$. Observe that $\binom{n}{i} / \binom{n}{i-1} = (n-i+1) / i \ge (n-k+1) / k$ for $i \le k$. Let $r = (n-k+1)/k$. Then $r > 1$ and
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i} \le \sum_{j=0}^\infty r^{-j} \binom{n}{k} = \frac1{1-r^{-1}} \binom{n}{k} = (1 + k / (n-2k+1)) \binom{n}{k}.$$
If $k$ is not too close to $n/2$ then this is much better than your bound.
